# Can I vertically offset an element in a CSS Grid cell?

Tags: html, css

Using this code:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Which can be seen and run here: `https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid`

Would it be possible to add a css style to one of the div elements (or by some other way) to vertically offset one of the numbers by say 15 pixels.

Say specifically, to offset the 5 in the center cell by say 15 pixels vertically?

(If the attached image works then I've mocked up what I mean).

Thanks.

[image]
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb0xi.png)

Comment: Is this a question about how to select the 'center cell' or is it about displacing its contents (for which you could use translateY without affecting anything else or needing to know the existing padding etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you're free to apply most of the CSS rules to grid children.

You can add a separate class to specific elements you want offset, i.e. `grid-item__offset`, and a rule with 15px of bottom padding:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item__offset {
  padding: 0 0 15px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item__offset">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `nth-child` [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to select the 5th element and adjust the padding on that element. See marked up code below.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(5) {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all of the replies. They have helped me learn and find a solution.